# Obtener valores semanales o mensuales

Tags: mysql, sql, subconsultas

antes que nada agradecerles su colaboración.

Estoy realizando una consulta que debo anidar y no consigo dar con la tecla.

Por un lado obtengo el número de horas diarias que duerme una persona, pero necesito mostrarlas semanalmente o mensualmente, para exponer en una gráfica cuánto duerme cada día, y sólo me sale el valor de la suma de horas semanales o mensuales. No consigo mostrar cada día lo que duerme durante una semana o mes.

Les dejo mi sql para obtener las horas dormidas a diario y a ver si alguien se le ocurre cómo podría hacer una semanal o mensual sin necesidad de esos datos incrustrarlos en una nueva tabla.

Gracias.

```
SELECT A.ID, SUM(A.horasDormidas) AS horasDia
FROM (
  SELECT valoresSens.id, HOUR(valoresSens.fecha) AS horasMedidas,
   ((AVG(valoresSens.valor))) >= '70' AS horasDormidas
  FROM valoresSens
  WHERE (date(fecha) between now() - INTERVAL 1 DAY AND now() ) 
    AND valoresSens.id = '22001'
  GROUP BY id, horasMedidas
  ORDER BY fecha asc) A 
GROUP BY A.ID
```

Comment: Por favor, modifica la pregunta e incorpora la estructura de las tablas en SQL con algún registro para las pruebas (phpMyAdmin,Exportar) y así podamos montar un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Indica exactamente el resultado que quieres obtener para esos datos de ejemplo. Aquí se explica mucho mejor [ask]. Bienvendo a [so]

Comment: El `ORDER BY fecha asc` es irrelevante. Es mejor que lo borres, o que lo muevas al final de la consulta.

Answer (score 0):

al no tener la estructura de tablas no puedo replicar el escenario.

pero tratando de ayudarte, lo que puedes hacer es sumar la cantidad de horas diarias y agruparlas por día de la semana y luego semana del año, algo así:

```
SELECT
 SUM(campo_horas) as horasDormidas,
 WEEKDAY(campo_fecha)  as dia,
 WEEK(campo_fecha)  as semana
FROM 
 miTabla
GROUP BY
 semana,
 dia
```

espero te sirva.

Comment: Un group by no puede recibir para agrupación una columna que resultó de usar una función de agregación como sum para este caso la columna calculada de hrs dormidas, alcanza con que la quites sino daría error

Comment: tienes razón, corregí la query.